# Disposing a static StreamWriter in a static class

Tags: c#, static

I have the following logger class, which prints colored messages into the console and writes them to a file (log.txt) on each `Logger.WriteLine("Hello World")` call.

If you wonder about the `_locker`, it's just because multi-threading messes up the console colors, because `Console.ForegroundColor` is set globally.

Since my class is static, I'm not quite sure if and/or when I should `Close()` and `Dispose()` the static StreamWriter object, because in the end it's static and it shouldn't really have any impact, but I feel like that's not correct.

Opinions?

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Logger class.
/// </summary>
public static class Logger
{
    private static readonly object _locker = new object();
    private static readonly StreamWriter _sw = new StreamWriter("log.txt");

    public static void WriteLine(string message, ConsoleColor color = ConsoleColor.Gray)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = color;
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            Console.ResetColor();
        }

        _sw.WriteLine(message);
        _sw.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well unless you have multiple App Domains I wouldn't worry about it.  It will be disposed when the Primary App Domain is unloaded which just happens to be when your Windows process exits.  All Win32 handles (including files) are automatically closed when the process exits.  Normally you might have to worry about flushing but I see you are already doing a `Flush`

Comment: @MickyD, thanks for confirming that!